# Getting all rows with NaN value

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a table with a column that has some NaN values in it:

```
A   B   C   D
2   3   2   Nan
3   4   5   5
2   3   1   Nan
```

I'd like to get all rows where D = NaN. How can I do this?

Comment: Is the data in a pandas dataframe or a csv file?

Comment: The data is in a CSV file.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Creating a df for illustration (containing Nan)

```
In [86]: df =pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[3,4,5],'c':[np.nan, 4,5]})

In [87]: df
Out[87]: 
   a  b   c
0  1  3 NaN
1  2  4   4
2  3  5   5
```

Checking which indices have null for column c

```
In [88]: pd.isnull(df['c'])
Out[88]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: c, dtype: bool
```

Checking which indices dont have null for column c

```
In [90]: pd.notnull(df['c'])
Out[90]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: c, dtype: bool
```

Selecting rows of df where c is not null

```
In [91]: df[pd.notnull(df['c'])]
Out[91]: 
   a  b  c
1  2  4  4
2  3  5  5
```

Selecting rows of df where c is null

```
In [93]: df[pd.isnull(df['c'])]
Out[93]: 
   a  b   c
0  1  3 NaN
```

Selecting rows of column c of df where c is not null

```
In [94]: df['c'][pd.notnull(df['c'])]
Out[94]: 
1    4
2    5
Name: c, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

For a solution that doesn't involve pandas, you can do something like:

```
goodind=np.where(np.sum(np.isnan(y),axis=1)==0)[0] #indices of rows non containing nans
```

(or the negation if you want rows with nan) and use the indices to slice data.
I am not sure `sum` is the best way to combine booleans, but `np.any` and `np.all` don't seem to have a `axis` parameter, so this is the best way I found.

Comment: Thank you, this solution was most helpful to me.